# Is it ok to ask for word suggestions by a native english speaker?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm a native english speaker, but with a terrible vocabulary, I sometimes find myself struggling (even after searching through an online thesaurus) to remember words (that I've heard before) to convey a thought or feeling. Is it OK to post such questions on this site? (Especially if I think that such questions would benefit a non native english speaker?)

Comment: [Word request](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-request), [Idiom request](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-request) on English Language Learning and [single-word request](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests), [idiom request](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-requests) on English Language and Usage are very popular tags. You can visit the links and see what kind of questions have been asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like answering those sorts of questions, because I enjoy finding a word that precisely expresses my meaning. Just be sure to give a detailed description of what you're trying to say, including whether you want a negative, positive, or neutral connotation. It also helps to have an example sentence that shows how you would like to use the word, if you have a specific context in mind.

You shouldn't limit yourself to asking native speakers though. Some of our non-native speakers are quite fluent and have a unique perspective.